# Copy cell from on sheet to another, if other cell in row matches values

Tags: google-sheets, copy, google-sheets-query

What I want, is to copy a cell(s) from one sheet to another, only if another cell in the same row (different column) have/has a particular value(s) in Google Sheets.

Ideally, I would like this to be live; if I add a row in the first sheet and the criterion matches, the second sheet will update too. Here's an example:

```
Sheet one

Column A | Column(s)…  | Column D
=================================
Hello    |             | Yes
World!   |             | Yes
Foo      |             | Maybe
Bar      |             |

Sheet two

Column A | Column(s)…  | Column D
=================================
Hello    |             |
World!   |             |
Foo      |             |
         |             |
```

So in this example, my criteria is that if the row's cell in `Column D` equals either `Yes` or `Maybe`, that row's cell in `Column A` is copied into the second sheet.

Comment: There may be similar solution to the problem in Excel!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query('Sheet one'!A:D,"Select A where D='Yes' or D='Maybe'")
```

Comment: That should do it. Don't know why I thought of a script. Probably thought that OP wanted to remove the row on the first sheet. :-|

Comment: Thanks, pnuts ! I undeleted it. When the last line is commented out it the row won't be removed..

Answer (score 1):

Paste below script in the script editor (of a google sheet that is) and save the project. Then try editing col D of sheet1 (values: 'Yes' or 'Maybe') and see if the row moves... Feel free to change the sheetnames if needed...

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = e.source,
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || e.range.columnStart !== 4 || e.value !== 'Yes' && e.value !== 'Maybe') return;
e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
    .appendRow(e.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 4)
        .getValues()[0]);
sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```